# Make vs Makes in a Sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Your motivation and expertise already (make/makes) you a great asset to our team and we can’t wait to see you become a leader in this company.

Answer (score 1):

Your motivation makes you a great asset, and your expertise makes you great too, but together they **make** you a future leader.